# Как прочитать 1ю строку из файла?

Tags: файлы, php

Есть файл на ~5 млн строк.
Как можно достать из него первую строку, если знаешь её длину, при этом не считывая файл полностью?

Comment: Спасибо, еще один момент забыл. 
Строку из файла нужно удалить.

Comment: Чтобы удалить строку, нужно полностью прочитать файл и заново записать без одной строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
$str = fgets($f, 1024);
или просто
$str = fgets($f);

resource fopen ( string $filename , string $mode [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context ]] )
string fgets ( resource $handle [, int $length ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

- [fopen](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php)
- [fread](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fread.php)